# How to sum values for second id basing on first id

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Let's assume I have table1:

```
id  id_2  value1 
1   999    1    
2   999    0    
3   998    0       
4   998    0    
5   997    1       
6   997    1
```

And I want to produce output like this - sum values for id_2 basing on count for id

```
 id_2  number_of 
  999    1    
  998    0    
  997    2
```

What approach would be suggested?

(DB: Oracle 12c)

Comment: Hint:  This is a basic `group by` query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the group by clause in order to collate the values for a particular Id as shown below

```
select id_2,
       sum(value1) number_of
  from table1
  group by id_2
  order by id_2 desc;
```

Comment: It's "id_2", not "id2"...

Comment: Thanks Mauro I have corrected this now